# Is there a "Choose Your Own Adventure" style of character creator?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

I have never played D&D before, but was thinking of getting a character going to play with a group of friends.

I was told that there might be a "choose your own adventure" type of walkthrough that, after completing, would tell you which type of character you were. This seemed appealing to me as it allows you to back into your character type.

Is there such a thing or something similar?

Comment: There appears to be a little bit of confusion as to what you're actually looking for. Are you looking for an **adventure module** you can run by yourself to perhaps get a feeling for the character/class you want to play? Or are you looking for one of those [what tv character am I?](http://www.seventeen.com/fun/quizzes/celebrity/which-fall-tv-character-are-you) style questionnaires (or something along that line) to help determine what character/class you should play? Or neither of these two options (if this is the case we need more detail regarding what you want).

Comment: You may be thinking of lifepath-style character creation, which, to my knowledge, D&D does not really have, at least in any widely recognized form.

Comment: The 4e red box has this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for help in choosing a class to play.

While I'm not aware of any "choose your own adventure" tools for taking you through the process of making the choice, I do have some advice for you.

Creating a character seems like it's about the mechanical choices that you make, but it's really about one question: what role do you want to play in the story?

That is, when things are happening, what part do you want to play a part in them?

Some things that happen in roleplaying games:

- Talking to people for various purposes (gathering information, negotiating, fast-talking your way into places you shouldn't be, trying to intimidate your way out of trouble, just having fun, etc)
- Problem-solving in various ways (scaling walls, disarming traps, finding clues, figuring out puzzles, investigating things, etc)
- Fighting

Everyone gets involved with the fighting part in some way, so you want to know what you're going to do when there are no other options. Are you going to get in the middle of things, or stay outside? Do you want to fight with finesse or with brute force? Do you rely on armor and shield, fancy footwork, magical wards, or do you simply shrug off the damage?

When there's no fighting, how do you spend your time? Do you want to be in the middle of the conversation? Or do you stay back, letting others take the lead, waiting for the blades to be drawn (or maybe even helping that happen)?

How do you get people to talk to you? Charming secrets out of tipsy nobles with your feminine wiles (or beefy charms) is very different from scaring answers out of conspirators with a blade to their throat.

Once you have thought through these things, take a look at the initial descriptions of each of the classes in the PHB. They start with some prose that describes what that class is like in play. Choose the one of those that sounds best to you.

You may also want to talk to the other players to see what they're doing. If "brooding merchant of death" is already being done at the table, then maybe you want to try something different. Or maybe you want to partner up and be brood brothers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any that are "Choose Your Own Adventure" -- that is, that you can play on your own without a Dungeon Master running for you.

The ones I do know of allow a DM to run a solo or group adventure for characters with basic stats, but no character class -- most of them will use the way you choose to solve the adventure (fighting, diplomacy, trickery, magic, etc) to provide guidance at the end on what class best suits your play style for that character.

If you and fellow players don't mind extending the period when your characters are relatively powerless, these "Level 0" or "apprentice-level" adventures can be a lot of fun.

So far as I know, there aren't any published adventures written this way for 5th Edition yet, but one of the earliest of these was the classic [N4 Treasure Hunt](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/17058/N4-Treasure-Hunt-1e) for 1st edition AD&D; which probably wouldn't be difficult for a DM to adapt.  (As a bonus, it has a lot of well-written guidance for DMs, both new and experienced.)

There are also many other 0-level adventures (official and un-) written for later editions of D&D -- happy hunting!

Aside from that, Michael Long provides an adventure outline at [D&D 5e Apprentice Character Update](http://tribality.com/2014/10/05/dd-5e-apprentice-character-update/), and there's an interesting discussion of the considerations on [Running a Level 0 Session in D&D 5e](http://dungeonleft.com/2014/09/20/running-a-level-0-session-in-dd-5e/) at the Dungeon Left blog.

Comment: As I read the question, Tyler is looking for a guided approach to character creation, not a DM-less adventure.

Comment: @kevin.matheny It's actually kind of hard to tell what he's asking for. We should wait for some clarification.

Comment: Agreed - that's why I didn't downvote this answer.

Comment: IMHO 5e treats 1st level a lot like 0-level as it takes a mere 300 XP to move to 2nd level. The days of slogging through thousands of experience points to get your wizard to 3rd level are over.